# How to get all browser history on Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, browser-history, android-browser

I know the permission `com.android.browser.permission.READ HISTORY BOOKMARKS` permission was removed from Android version 6 and API level 18+. But is there any way to get all the browser history from the android app project?

Comment: There are dozens upon dozens of browser apps for Android. None have to provide an API for accessing bookmarks, let alone some single place you can go to get them.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get it but is there any third party package or something to finish this job?